# for of loop statement push keys and value into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, key, key-value

I'm having some slight trouble with this code. The problem for it seemed easy enough; to push the keys into my array and then push the values into my array separately. Yet, when I have the code returned to me, it shows that nothing is pushed into my array, and it tells me the function parameter "obj" isn't iterable. I'm not sure what's wrong.

```
function giveMeFive(obj){
  //coding here
  
  var arr=[];
  
  for(var key in obj){
   if( (key.length==5)){
     arr.push(obj[key]);
   }   
 }
  for(var value of obj){
    if(value.length==5){
    arr.push(obj[value]);
      }
    }
   return arr;
  }
```

Comment: Can you update your question with a [mcve]? You can use the snippet (`[<>]`) tool in the toolbar. It really needs the object that you're calling the function with, and your expected output.

Comment: for..of needs to be used with iterable. If you passing plain js object as key value pairs, you need to call for (var value of Object.values(obj)) and push value insteaf of obj[value]